# Resize a MovieClip on AS2 in function of text len?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

i have a AS2 script who get information from a MySQL database. This information is a text from 0 to 300 chars. I want to display that text in this layout:
[alt text http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/3287/layoutb.png](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/3287/layoutb.png)

I want to resize the black box you see on the picture in function of the amount of text imported. Any idea of how to do that on AS2?

The instance name of the box is: **cargador.fondo** (only want to resize height)
The instance name of the text is: **cargador.texto**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

cargador.texto.autoSize = "left";
cargador.texto.wordWrap = true;
cargador.texto.multiline = true;